# VBS Can't printscreen

Tags: vbscript

I recently picked up VBScript and I was messing with the sendkey commands when I noticed that the {PRTSC} isn't working on my computer.

My Program: I made it so that it'll take a screenshot and paste it.

```
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 1000
objShell.sendKeys "{prtsc}"
objShell.SendKeys "^V"
```

Is there something wrong with the code or am I not understanding something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note 
You cannot send the PRINT SCREEN key {PRTSC} to an application.

From Help https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx

Also Sendkeys is part of Windows Scripting Host not VBScript.

Comment: How do we get around this then?